# How to interpret I and Q components of a GPS baseband signal?

Tags: gps, qgis-processing

I am designing an RF frontend for GPS using [MAX2769](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2769.pdf) chip. However, due to lack of theoretical and practical background in signal processing and knowledge about GPS, I am unsure how to interpret the I and Q baseband signals which are the output of MAX2769.

1. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_signals#Frequencies_used_by_GPS), the Q component carries the data for civilian use. Since I can't decrypt the military data, can I completely ignore the I component (in L1)?
2. Do the bits encoded in I and Q correspond to the data structures defined in the official GPS specifications[0] (Appendix III, page 153 specifically)?
3. Why do I get 2 bits for I and 2 bits for Q component from MAX2769, when they only encode zeros and ones?

[0] `http://www.gps.gov/technical/icwg/IS-GPS-200H.pdf` (I can't post more than two links)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, questions here should only ask one question, they must demonstrate adequate research, and be focused on geographic information systems. This question might be more appropriate in an electronics-centric SE.